# MongoDB Assertion Error: starting_from == self.__retrieved (pymongo driver)

Tags: mongodb, replication, pymongo, sharding, assertion

MongoDB Question:

We're using a sharded replicaset, running pymongo 2.2 against mongo (version: 2.1.1-pre-).  We're getting a traceback when a query returns more than one result document.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/opt/DCM/mods/plugin.py", line 25, in run
  self._mod.collect_metrics_dcm()
File "/opt/DCM/plugins/res.py", line 115, in collect_metrics_dcm
  ms.updateSpecificMetric(metricName, value, timestamp)
File "/opt/DCM/mods/mongoSaver.py", line 155, in updateSpecificMetric
  latestDoc = self.getLatestDoc(metricName)
File "/opt/DCM/mods/mongoSaver.py", line 70, in getLatestDoc
  for d in dlist:
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 747, in next
  if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 698, in _refresh
  self.__uuid_subtype))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 668, in __send_message
  assert response["starting_from"] == self.__retrieved
AssertionError
```

The code that give what dlist is is a simple find().  I've tried reIndex(), no joy.  I've tried stopping and starting the mongo server, no joy.

This is easily replicable for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so traced this down a bit, and I have a SOLUTION for this assertion error.

**There is a BUG in Mongo.**  When querying a sharded replicaset, Mongo returns an incorrect value for 'starting_from'.  Instead of returning 0 on the first query, it's returning the number of records received instead of the offset value.  I have a patch for pymongo to protect against this bad info:

File is site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py.

```
[user@hostname]$ diff cursor.py.orig cursor.py
631,632c631,634
<         if not self.__tailable:
<             assert response["starting_from"] == self.__retrieved
---
>   if ((not self.__tailable) and (self.__retrieved != 0) and (response["starting_from"] != self.__retrieved)):
>             from pprint import pformat
>             msg = "Server response of 'starting_from' is '%s', but self__retrieved (which is only set to nonzero below here) is '%s'." % (pformat(response), pformat(self.__retrieved))
>             assert False, msg
```

The 'starting_from' comes from helpers.py decoding the response from Mongo:

```
result["starting_from"] = struct.unpack("<i", response[12:16])[0]
```

So, it's the 12th thru the 15th byte of Mongo's response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the 2.1.1 development release of mongos. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5844